# WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I encountered this error,

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

And once I got into the fusion folder, I couldn't find the `EnableLog` file, can you please help me?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to turn assembly bind logging on if you wish to diagnose a problem with loading assemblies. If you need to do this, the best way to turn logging on temporarily is using the Fusion Log Viewer, fuslogvw.exe. Instructions on how to use it can be found [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)

Comment: well now the log entry showed detailed information about a failed assembly bind, do you have any suggestions how to deal with it?

Comment: The log of the failed bind will determine what you need to do. Does the assembly exist in the right path? Do you need to install it to the GAC? Is it a missing 3rd party product? Is there a version mismatch? The log will explain

Answer (score 0):

Updating 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 1.1.0' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 1.1.2' solved this problem for me